Movie where man sleeps with Native American woman and ends up married to her
There's a movie I saw years ago that had a scene where this guy has sex with a Native American woman, walks out of the teepee the next morning, and the whole tribe is standing there cheering because he actually ended up marrying her. Later in the movie, the woman is wearing cowboy-ish clothes and pretty much became a badass gunslinger. I remember the movie was more funny than anything, at least for those scenes. 
Any clue what the title is?

This is a fairly common trope in Westerns and any film where a foreigner meets a native tribe, see 'Accidental Marriage' on TVTropes, but I'm sure your referring to Shanghai Noon, the 2000 comedy movie staring Luke Wilson and Jackie Chan. Jackie's Chon Wang was the guy in question. The wife was only credited as Indian Wife, played by actress Brandon Merrill. They end up not married in the end. 


YEAH! That's exactly it! Thanks a bunch, it was driving me nuts all night!
